# WPF datagrid "EditItem is not allowed for this view" exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I programmatically add `DataGrid`:

```
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
dataGrid.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.None;
dataGrid.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;
dataGrid.Background = Brushes.White;
DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
textColumn.Width = 250;
textColumn.Header = "Account";
textColumn.Binding = new Binding("Account");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
```

When I add Item:

> Globals_Liker.list_datagrid[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Items.Add(Globals_Liker.list_item[tabControl1.SelectedIndex][i]);

But if I doubleclick on Items I have error:

> "EditItem" is not allowed for this view.

How to make that error does not pop up?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You `should not update the Items directly of your DataGrid` but rather set the `ItemsSource` to the collection. DataGrid will generate the view out of the itemsource that implements `IEditableCollectionView` interface in order to allow the editing. This interface has function `EditItems()` which let the editing happen.

So in order solve this problem. Create the `ObservableCollection` property in your VM/Code behind and set the DataGrid ItemsSource to it like

```
ObservableCollection<Type> MyCollection{get;set;}


Globals_Liker.list_datagrid[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].ItemsSource = MyCollection;
```

In your constructor you can initialize this collection by newing it. And whenever you want to add item in your `DataGrid`, just add the item in the Observable collection (MyCollection), it will be shown on grid and will be editable.

Answer (score 4):

**I seen this error in 3 cases**

**case1** : this error shown if double clicking the datagrid then(custom datagrid which contains processed data like analysis)

Simply, Set in Datagrid IsReadOnly="True"

**case2** : this error shown after editing the datagrid, must set during RowEditEnding

```
  (sender as DataGrid).CommitEdit(DataGridEditingUnit.Row);
```

**case3** : this error shown after RowEditEnding event, then must see where the datagrid is reloading the data, it can happen if viewsource or datagrid is already in use and we try to override the data manually

Let me know if any new cases you seen

Answer (score 2):

this works for me

```
InitializeComponent();
datagrid.BeginningEdit += (s, ss) => ss.Cancel = true;
```

I tried wiht IsReadOnly="True", but it doesn't allow me to check and uncheck the checkbox on the datagrid