# WPF DataGrid EditItem exception

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I have a `TabControl` and add `TabItem` on `TabControl` with `DataGrid`. But if I double click on range crashes:

> "EditItem" is not allowed for this view.

```
                    System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
 DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
                    textColumn.Header = "ID";
                    textColumn.Binding = new Binding("ID");
                    dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);
                    item.Content = dataGrid;
                    tabControl1.Items.Add(item);
```

When add Item:

```
list_datagrid[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Items.Add(.list_item[tabControl1.SelectedIndex][i]);
```

Please tell me how to remove the error.

Answer (score 5):

Set the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid`  to the collection that `DataGrid` can use to generate the view that implements  `IEditableCollectionView` . This interface has function `EditItem()` which let the editing happen.

I have answered the similar question here [WPF datagrid "EditItem is not allowed for this view" exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334326/wpf-datagrid-edititem-expation/19334755#19334755)

Comment: The collection doesn't need to implement `IEditableCollectionView`. In fact, `ObservableCollection` doesn't implement that interface and implementing it doesn't resolve the exception. I'm still looking for a way to convince WPF to use a collection view that can be edited, for my custom collection.