# Edititem is not allowed for this view list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have tried for hours and hours but I cannot edit the column quantity in datagrid, whenever I do it gives me an error saying that

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: 'EditItem' is not allowed for this view.

My xaml code is

```
<DataGrid EnableRowVirtualization="True" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGrid1" IsReadOnly="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" Margin="10,10,10,10" PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown" SelectionChanged="DataGrid1_SelectionChanged" CellEditEnding="DataGrid1_CellEditEnding" CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" BeginningEdit="DataGrid1_BeginningEdit" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Name" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=ItemName}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Item Price" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=ItemPrice}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="QuantityColumn" Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="False"  Binding="{Binding Path=Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Price" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=TotalPrice}" Width="*">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

and here is C# code

```
List<AddItem> DATA = new List<AddItem>()
{
    new AddItem()
    {
        ItemName = ItemName.Text.ToString(),
        ItemPrice = float.Parse(ItemPrice.Text.ToString()),
        Quantity = quantity.Text,
        TotalPrice = CalculateTotalPrice()
    }
};
DataGrid1.Items.Add(DATA);

public class AddItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
    public float ItemPrice { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Where am I going wrong? I have tried observable collection also still no solution?
Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Real answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19334755/1599699

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign the `List<AddItem>` list to the `ItemSource` instead of `Add` like so:

Use

```
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = DATA;
```

instead of

```
DataGrid1.Items.Add(DATA);
```

Other improvements to your code:

- Use `decimal` type for **all** prices (always)
- Use `int` type for quantity since quantity represent a number

Comment: But then i wont be able to add items one by one if i make it to itemsource

Comment: @NelsonCajetinDiegoAlfonso use a `BindingList<T>` instead of `List<T>`, link it as i mentioned in my answer. You will be able to add items later with e.g. `DATA.Add(new AddItem { ItemName = "foo", ItemPrice = 160 });` once it is binded. When you add it to the list ... not directly to the datagrid.

Comment: @NelsonCajetinDiegoAlfonso be more precise ;-)  what about it ?

Comment: Should i add the DATA to the data table and then bind it to the itemsource? will it be better?

Comment: @NelsonCajetinDiegoAlfonso nope that doesn't matter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129188/discussion-between-jim-and-nelson-cajetin-diego-alfonso).